# FAILURE: Build failed with exception

Tags: android, gradle, merge, aapt, aapt2

```
> Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
> 
> WARNING: The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not
> be used anymore. Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this
> warning. It will be removed at the end of 2018. :app:preBuild
> UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugAidl
> UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
> :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
> UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
> :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResources
> UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT error: check logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

> BUILD FAILED in 13s 9 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 8 up-to-date
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AAPT2 error: check logs for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47589873/aapt2-error-check-logs-for-details)

Comment: First of all, you probably disabled AAPT2 with the android.enableAapt2 flag because you were getting errors from AAPT2. Now you're getting errors from AAPT1 - meaning there's something actually wrong with your resources. The errors should be visible in the full build log. If you're having trouble finding it, you can manually run it by going to the project directory and executing "./gradlew clean assembleDebug".

Comment: Yes, I see this error in my build after Android Studio was upgraded to 3.1

Comment: You need to post your whole build log so we can see what the problem is. Run "./gradlew clean assembleDebug" in your project directory and post the output in the question.

Comment: Also try with a newer gradle plugin - 3.2.0-alpha11 or newer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to find aapt2 logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48400895/where-to-find-aapt2-logs)

Answer (score 25):

In gradle.properties change `android.enableAapt2=false` to `true`

Comment: after changed it to true, got error `hdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png: error: uncompiled PNG file passed as argument. Must be compiled first into .flat file..
`

Comment: I am facing same issue, when i have updated my Android Studio. I have change android.enableAapt2=false to true and it works for me.

Comment: Sorry, but from what I have read this hides the warning but I am not sure if this will solve the actual issue.

Comment: (1) update android studio (2) restart android studio (3) set `android.enableAapt2` to true

Comment: Earlier was getting this error :The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore. After making true getting this error :Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Answer (score 3):

You can actually have problems in the resources but these will not be displayed if you do not correct this problem first:

> The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used
>   anymore. Use 'android.enableAapt2 = true' to remove this warning. It
>   will be removed at the end of 2018.

within your `gradle.properties` file that is located in the root of the project, replace:

```
android.enableAapt2
```

with:

```
android.enableAapt2 = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your gradle plugin. Fixed my error.

Answer (score 0):

within gradle.properties file that is located in the root of the project,

I have just commented on this line, now works perfectly

android.enableAapt2 = true

Answer (score -2):

Please make sure that the images and icons you  included in your project is Imported by android studio or  Drawable importer plugin.

to install this plugin you have to go File>setting> plugin.
then type Drawable importer

[image]

Comment: This has to do with Gradle properties when syncing. This isn't even close to the same thing.

Answer (score -4):

Your problem is with `android.enableAapt2` .
You should check what's missing or the package is imported correctly.
Search for file `android.enableAapt2` or that keyword.

Comment: The "android.enableAapt2" message is just a warning, since AAPT1 will be deprecated soon and so disabling AAPT2 is not recommended. The real errors should be visible in the build log.