# Not show concrete error resource. Double click on error - not resolve problem

Tags: android-studio

Andoid Studio 3.4

I build my project by I get error:

[image]

I double click on line with error, but nothing happend. It's not show where is a concrete error? In what class, xml or smt. else.

Why?

Comment: Can you try?  `File --> Invalidate Caches / Restart --> Invalidate and Restart`

Comment: @RKURBAN invalidate caches and restart isn't a magical, fix-all solution. Especially when this is the way Android Studio is designed, for reasons I cannot understand

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48400895/6296561)

Answer (score 0):

Try:
Select Build menu then Click on Clean Project

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually related to problems in your XML files and is known to not be pointed/resolved by Android Studio itself; The possiblities goes on duplicated headers on XML files or misspelled atributes that the IDE for some reason couldn't identify or highlight.

You could first try to rebuild, then try to invalidate cache and restart Android Studio and if the error persists, try to undo the last modifications to your XML files

see [failed linking file resource. - I am getting this error even after trying all possible solution provided by others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48549587/failed-linking-file-resource-i-am-getting-this-error-even-after-trying-all-po)